# why I am not create object in useEffect in hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, web-worker

I am trying to use `webworker` in our demo application, but I am not able to create instance of my `worker`. I get the error worker` is read only. Why?

Here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-forest-s3guc?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import worker from "./workerfile";
import WebWorker from "./setup";
export default function App() {
  const buttonHan = () => {
    alert("==g=");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // worker = new WebWorker(worker);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <button onClick={buttonHan}>BTN</button>

      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The iissue is when I am creating a object of worker in `useEffect` in the below line.

```
 // worker = new WebWorker(worker);
```

On button click, I want to send `trigger` to my worker for calculation.

Comment: You are assigning worker a value but probably you just want to use it to init a new WebWorker. Try just `new WebWorker(worker);` instead. Remove the `worker = `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two lines that are in conflict.

```
import worker from "./workerfile";
```

and

```
    // worker = new WebWorker(worker);
```

You first import from a file and assign the value to a variable named `worker`.

You should not then later change that value. If you must use that name you can shadow-scope your variable by including a block-scope keyword such as `let` or `const`. But you can also just redefine the variable name (e.g. `myWorker` or similar).

Answer (score 1):

The const value `worker` is the default export and therefore readonly. I assume you want to use the `worker` object for the creation of the WebWorker.

Just remove the part where you are storing the created WebWorker in the worker constant variable.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import worker from "./workerfile";
import WebWorker from "./setup";
export default function App() {
  const buttonHan = () => {
    alert("==g=");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    new WebWorker(worker);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <button onClick={buttonHan}>BTN</button>

      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```